# Plot not displaying

Tags: trigonometry

I'm trying to perform a basic plot to show that two equations align, but I'm not getting any results.

Plot[{[Pi]*Cos (3 x - [Pi]), [Pi] * Sin (3*[Pi] - 3 x)}, {x, -3 [Pi], 3 [Pi]}]

To me this seems fairly straightforward, but I'm getting a graph without the functions.

Comment: related: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/18393/8

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer quicker than I thought. I was using "(" and ")" for Sin and Cos when I should have been using "[" and "]". Rookie mistake.